# Expected null or template in return value from inclusion function

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm developing user registration/login feature in my Meteor app from scratch. I'm basing on this tutorial: https://waaave.com/tutorial/meteor/design-a-complete-authentication-system-with-meteor/

When I try to reset my password, I'm getting this error (after clicking on reset password link from email):

```
Expected null or template in return value from inclusion function, found: *token-string-printed-here*
```

I've found so far that it might be new Meteor templating system fault - Blaze, when returning null of no value - anyone know how to solve this? Please help.

I've found this link - maybe it will help someone help me :) :

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes

Comment: This error occurs when you white `{{> foo}}` and `foo` is not a template. Please revisit your code to find if this might be the problem. It is also possible that the error lurks in one of the packages you are using, which has not yet been updated to the latest Version of Meteor.

Comment: what does that 'white' mean?

Comment: He's meaning "write" (probably a typo). I have migrated all my applications to Meteor 0.8 and the forget password feature still works so it is not due to Blaze.

Comment: Yes what I meant was "write", sorry for that ;) Thank you @JulienLeCoupanec :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution for my problem - it was the fault of duplicate names. I had `resetPassword` variable and `resetPassword` template - renaming the template to `resetPasswordTemplate` solved the problem.

Comment: yeah - now I'm naming every template with `template` suffix and I advise everyone to do the same.